# Is this query OK? [Oracle 8i]

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle8i

I've got this query in Oracle 11g [working fine]:

```
select (case
         when seqnum = 1 then
         t.DPR_N
         when seqnum = cnt then
          '0'
       end) as VALUE1,
       (case
         when seqnum = 1 then
          t.BEGIN_DT
         when seqnum = cnt then
         t.END_DT
       end) as timestamp,

       t2.APP_NAAM || '.SUBBATCH_TRIGGER' TAGNAME1

  from (select t.*,t6.*,
               row_number() over(partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.PLANT_UNIT,t6.DPR_ID order by t.BEGIN_DT) as seqnum,
               count(*) over(partition by t.BATCH_ID, t.PLANT_UNIT,t6.DPR_ID) as cnt

 FROM tb_unit_step t
INNER JOIN tb_equipment t2
ON t2.PLANT_UNIT = t.PLANT_UNIT

INNER JOIN tb_rs3 t3
ON t.BATCH_ID = t3.BATCH_ID

INNER JOIN tb_cpm t9
ON t9.BACPM_ID = t3.BACPM_ID

INNER JOIN tb_step t4
ON (t9.BV_ID    = t4.BV_ID
AND t.STAP_NR1 = t4.STAP_NR1
AND t.STAP_NR2 = t4.STAP_NR2)
INNER JOIN tb_bv t5
ON t5.BV_ID = t9.BV_ID
INNER JOIN tb_bv_process t6
ON t9.BV_ID   = t6.BV_ID
AND t6.DPR_ID = t4.DPR_ID
INNER JOIN tb_ins t7
ON (t7.INS_ID = t4.INS_ID)
INNER JOIN tb_cpm t8
ON t8.BV_ID = t9.BV_ID

 WHERE  (t.BEGIN_DT > ? AND t.END_DT < ?)
     )  t
  join tb_equipment t2 on t2.plant_unit = t.plant_unit


 where (seqnum = 1
    or seqnum = cnt);
```

I've got to make it work on Oracle 8i [I know it's a REALLY old version, but I have no choice since it's not my DB]. I've built this query in order to get the data from Oracle 8i: [I've changed `CASE WHEN` for `DECODE` and removed all the `ANSI JOIN`s]

```
  SELECT DECODE(SEQNUM, 1, T.DPR_N,CNT,'0') VALUE1,
  DECODE(SEQNUM, 1, T.BEGIN_DT,CNT,T.END_DT) TIMESTAMP,

  '090.' || T2.APP_NAAM
  || '.SUBBATCH_TRIGGER' TAGNAME1
FROM
  (SELECT T.*,
    T6.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.BATCH_ID, T.PLANT_UNIT,T6.DPR_ID ORDER BY T.BEGIN_DT) SEQNUM,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY T.BATCH_ID, T.PLANT_UNIT,T6.DPR_ID) CNT
  FROM tb_unit_step T ,
    tb_equipment T2 ,
    tb_rs3 T3 ,
    tb_cpm T9 ,
    tb_step T4 ,
    tb_bv T5 ,
    tb_bv_process T6 ,
    tb_ins T7 ,
    tb_cpm T8
  WHERE T2.PLANT_UNIT = T.PLANT_UNIT
  AND T.BATCH_ID      = T3.BATCH_ID
  AND (T9.BV_ID       = T4.BV_ID
  AND T.STAP_NR1      = T4.STAP_NR1
  AND T.STAP_NR2      = T4.STAP_NR2)
  AND T5.BV_ID        = T9.BV_ID
  AND (T9.BV_ID       = T6.BV_ID
  AND T6.DPR_ID       = T4.DPR_ID)
  AND T7.INS_ID       = T4.INS_ID
  AND T8.BV_ID        = T9.BV_ID
  AND (T.BEGIN_DT     > '15-jul-2013'
  AND T.END_DT       < '01-aug-2014')
  ) T
  ,tb_equipment T2  
  WHERE T2.PLANT_UNIT = T.PLANT_UNIT
  AND (T.SEQNUM         = 1
  OR SEQNUM           = T.CNT)
  ;
```

The new query is definately not OK because it's taking forever to run. So what would be the correct form of the first query in order to get data from Oracle 8i?

UPDATE:

Result of the query:

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the execution plans on the 11g and 8i instances and see what it's doing differently. You may be seeing some effects from the rule-based optimiser, in which case simple things like changing the order the tables are listed could make a big difference (no, really; though I forget if that was the case in 8i, or only 7 and earlier). But first thing I'd do is get rid of the implicit date conversion, especially if `begin_dt` amd `end_dt` are indexed. Make it `begin_dt > to_date('15-jul-2013', 'dd-mon-yyyy')`. Implicit models are evil, and you may be converting every column value to a string.

Comment: OK, thanks! But I'm not sure if the second query is actually correct since I'm not an Oracle/DB developer. I've just applied the rules I've seen in other questions here :). PS.: I've applied your change now and the query is still running.. So I think we still have the same issue

Comment: Finished running the query. Result added to the question.

Comment: @dalek _explain plan for yourquery_. would give you _plan explained_ and then run _Select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)_. It prints your plan table result. In SQL*Plus do, _set linesize 2000;_ and _set pages 0:_ before running all this.. and the printed output will estimate the cost and the join cardinality for every table join. That would easily reveal the issue, and Alex was suggesting you do the same! The error you get is because of, a temp table is created for processing your query results, and since the cardinality is so high(a missing join) the number for rows generated is so huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see this condition in your Oracle 8 version:

```
t9.BACPM_ID = t3.BACPM_ID
```

That could explain the performance problem.